# Xamarin progress indicator while connecting to web server

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin.android

I'm facing a problem with Async operation when App starts.

During `OnCreate`, I start a background operation that call a web service to test if the service is available. In the activity, I have a label with `Connecting...` text. When the async operation completes, the label's text is changed to `OK` or `No service`.

Now the question is: can I show to my user that an async operation is in progress?

I cannot figure out how I can use another async operation can show some animation while the server responds and complete the second async operation when the first completes.

Answer (score 0):

You would ideally create a custom `View` which renders the animation (or use the SDK built-in indeterminate `ProgressBar`) and place it in your layout, with its [`visibility`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Views.View.Visibility/) set to [`ViewStates.Gone`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone/).

Before the async operation is launched, the view's `visibility` is set to `ViewStates.Visible`, and after the async operation completes, the `visibility` is again set to `Gone`. You may even remove the view from the layout if you want after the async operation completes.

You'd have something like (pseudo-C#)

```
async void OnCreate()
{
    // Some code (get references to views, etc.)

    progressView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

    var asyncResult = await SomeAsyncOperation();

    progressView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

    // Some more code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean with custom view? Is placed in the main view? Where can I find information?

Comment: [This](http://syedwasihaider.github.io/blog/2015/07/12/XamarinViews/) and [this](http://xandroid4net.blogspot.in/2014/09/custom-view.html) will help you in creating custom views in Xamarin.Android. Or, if you want the stock spinner that comes up in fully Material Design applications, take a look at [the `ProgressBar` widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).